# C# - Internet explorer interface

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, getelementsbytagname

I have written a macro in Excel-VBA that interfaces with Internet Explorer. Since then my company has asked if I can create an application that does not rely on MSOffice.

I've been trying to use C# but have found it far harder to use with IE than VBA. Part of the code I have is written below.

```
// Get map offset element
eOffset = IE.Document.getElementById("map-canvas").getElementsByTagName("div")[3];

//Get div span elements from eOffset
elements = eOffset.getElementsByTagName("span");

//Find the scale and distance elements, eScale being the first 
//child 'div' of the parent of eDist
rgx = new Regex("[1-9][0-9]* (mi|km)");
foreach (IHTMLElement o in elements)
{
    if (rgx.IsMatch(o.innerText))
    {
        eDist = o;
        eScale = o.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Searching on here I found that I should be using `IHTMLElement` and `IHTMLElementCollection` to avoid conflicts between `mshtml` and `system.windows.forms`. I can get `eOffset`, but now I'm stuck trying to get the child elements of `eOffset` with tag name "span", getting the error that `getElementsByTagName` cannot be used with `IHTMLElement`.

I've tried searching for a solution and using trial-and-error but so far have had no luck. Am I heading in the right direction or should I be trying an alternative method?

Comment: Hey Aaron, I too went through something similar years ago. Are you using visual studio? If you are there is a control called the web browser control. There is an awful lot you can do with it and it makes your application pretty independent.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Yes I am using visual studio, I'll look it up now. Thanks!